# Check Eclipse RepositoryProvider on a menu selection for plugin

Tags: xml, eclipse, plugins

I am writing a plugin and want to enable/disable popup menu items depending on whether the project has been configured with 'Share Project' for team support.

I am using the following to examine a selection for RepositoryProvider and it works fine in Navigator view. However, it does not work on the java files in Package Explorer. How do I check RepositoryProvider on java elements?
Thanks.

```
<adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.mapping.ResourceMapping">
   <test
      property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectPersistentProperty"
      args="org.eclipse.team.core.repository,com.abc.team.teamProvider">
   </test>
</adapt>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the use of org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource instead of org.eclipse.core.resources.mapping.ResourceMapping solved my problem.